# How to Open second activity when click push notification using Xamarin?

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I am implementing push notification using Xamarin. The push notification works fine and I can able to receive a push notification. When I click notification message the corresponding page is not open instead loading pop is showing for a long time. I have used the below code to open activity when clicking notification in android project. I want to call the method which is in the portable project from my new activity class.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(Push));
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
PendingIntent activity = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

I have called the view in portable project like below

```
public void test(parameters)
{
   await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new DescriptionPage(tileGrid, 
      m_eBookShortName, m_eBookName, false, downloadImage, deleteImageIcon, 
      m_downloadProgressbar));
}
```

What is the issue in my code? how can we launch xaml view when click push notification?